# New Unity Project Using Oculus Quest SDK has incompatible assembly references

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

When I create a new Unity standard project, select target plattform = android and include the unity oculus asset from the oculus archive, visual studie tells me that components from the oculus SDK could not be foundn, e.g. OVRHand (are you missing an assembly reference)

I also include the oculus xr plugin in the unity package manager.
VS 2019 are up to date,
unity version 2020.1.6f1

[image]
[image]
On the first trial, it worked. I cloned (and created a new) project, but on 2 other systems, I get this error below

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the assembly (e.g. ASsembly-CSharp-Editor), then click on reload project fixes it